# couldn't run mongo through a script

Tags: mongodb, bash, shell

I'm trying to launch mongo through my script after installing mongodb, but it throw an error but when I try "mongo" from my terminal it works perfectly.

Error when I run mongo from my script :

```
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.21
connecting to: test
2018-10-11T10:38:32.855+0200 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 
127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: 
errno:111 Connection refused

2018-10-11T10:38:32.877+0200 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't 
connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:229:14

@(connect):1:6

exception: connect failed
```

Here is a part of my script

```
apt-get install -y mongodb-org

systemctl enable mongod

systemctl start mongod

echo " " >> /etc/mongod.conf
echo "replication:" >> /etc/mongod.conf
echo "   oplogSizeMB: 1" >> /etc/mongod.conf
echo "   replSetName: rs0" >> /etc/mongod.conf

sed '24d' /etc/mongod.conf

systemctl restart mongod

export LC_ALL=C

mongo --eval "rs.initiate()"
```

But when i just run "mongo" command on my terminal it works :

```
# mongo
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.21
connecting to: test

rs0:OTHER>
```

what might be the problem, please?

Comment: Do you know for sure which line of your script is failing? Are you sure it is the mongo command, i.e. have you tried injecting an echo just before, or could it be one of the earlier systemctl mongo commands?

Comment: I tried by injecting some echos but stil the same problem... It throws an error when `mongo --eval "rs.initiate()"` command is excecuted.

Comment: Ok, just a thought, sorry. Divide and conquer.

Answer (score 0):

try with the following line:

```
/bin/bash -c "mongo --eval \"rs.initiate()\""
```

Comment: yes, that might help. In which case you could add a shebang at the top of your script to run the whole script with bash: `#!/usr/bin/env bash` On the other hand, if mongo is actually a script and requires bash, then it should have the shebang.

Comment: It not working :( however thank you for your responses